# ngx-bootstrap ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: v is not a function

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have two environments where I run my app and this component works on one, but not the other.

I import as follows in package.json

```
"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.7.1",
```

(I recently tried upgrading from "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.1", to try and fix the issue). In app.module, I import as follows:

```
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/timepicker';
```

I import this module in the imports as follows:

```
TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
```

Within a reactive form:

```
<timepicker formControlName="startTime" name="startTime" id="startTime"></timepicker>
```

In the ts component:

```
 this.activityForm = this.fb.group({
            ...
            startTime: ['', ''],
            ...
        });
```

where ... in place of fields not relevant to this question. It works fine, with a template form, but I am looking to move to reactive forms. The reactive form works on one machine, but not another.

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules folder on machine it doesn't work and run npm install again and see if it works.

Comment: I tried this. Running npm install ran very quickly, as if they had just been cached after delete and then readded. I tried again, whilst running npm cahce clean inbetween and it was still too fast to be installing everying. Is there another way to delete the cache?

Comment: Close the IDE, delete the folder manually. Open IDE run "npm cache clean". Then run npm install. Hope it helps!

Comment: Many thanks! They are reinstalling now. I will let you know if it worked once i check back after lunch.

Comment: Many many thanks! They installed just fine and it now works! Feel free to post an answer and I will accept it after lunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the node_modules folder on machine it doesn't work and run npm install again and see if it works. Steps:

```
 - Close the IDE, delete the folder manually. 
 - Open IDE run "npm cache clean". 
 - Then run npm install.
```

Hope it helps!